# how to set username and password in ms access

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I want to set username and password for my ms access database (*.accdb) file.

I dont to how to do.

There would be great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You mean encrypt the database? Also, do you want to this from code (I'm asking because of the C# tag)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you open your database? Please provide some.

Answer (score 0):

From [Encrypt Database with Password](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-HA010096299.aspx)

> In earlier versions of Access, you could create user accounts and
>   passwords using a feature called user-level security. This topic does
>   not discuss user-level security, which is not available when you use
>   the .accdb file format.

So you can no longer set a username and password.

To change or set a db password, You should be able to run a query against it something like:

```
 "ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD newpassword currentpassword"
```